# HTTP basic authentication in javascript, jquery or django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, http-authentication

I'm developing a web app (A) that serves as a "front-end" to another website (B), which requires a basic HTTP authentication (i.e., the kind that pops up and asks for a username and password).

In my web app, each user will already have his username and password for B stored as part of his account for A. However, the first time the user tries to access a resource in B from A, it prompts for the username and password (but then doesn't have to anymore for the rest of the session). I want it to be so that the user *never* has to explicitly enter his credentials (since they are already stored in his account).

Using javascript/jquery or some Django code, is it possible to pre-emptively authenticate this user behind the scenes, for example when they log in to A?  It should just be a simple matter of sending a request to some resource in B with the username and password, therefore

Thanks, I hope this question is clear.

Comment: Are A and B on completely different domains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can stick that straight in the URL.

http://user:pass@server.domain.tld/dir/file.ext

Comment: So that anybody sees your password?

Comment: @Secator ... It's basic HTTP Authentication.  Anyone can already see your password, because HTTP is a plaintext Protocol.  That's, infact, already the way your browser does it, just without telling you.  Optimally, this should be done with SSL, but that's not the question at hand.  The question was how to authenticate, and this is the quickest way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery ajax() method supports HTTP authentication with options "username" and "password".

[jQuery.ajax() manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> If the server performs HTTP authentication before providing a response, the user name and password pair can be sent via the username and password options.

B. VB.:

> It should just be a simple matter of sending a request to some resource in B with the username and password

I didn't test, but it's definitively worth a try. Probably as long as the server authorized the client then it should not prompt it for credentials again so that's worth a try.

Comment: OK, but how will you make an XHR request to the other website that is potentially on another origin? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, you probably can't do this without introducing a common authentication / security token sharing etc. mechanism that involves the B backend.

Since B is probably a different origin, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you from making a request to B from a page that's served from A.

If you're able to change the B backend, you could make a JSONP request (i.e. not basic authentication via HTTP headers) to B from a page on A when the user logs in to A.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on for inspiration for different solutions.